# linux c client - add ability of sending data

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I try to write a simple Client connecting to beej server stream
everything I wrote till now working fine.
now I want to add to the client the ability to send data witch he gets from the user and I don't know how to do it(without using scanf ofc).
how can I do it?
this is my code :

```
// chat client 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT 9034 // defined port like the server
void main()
{
    char * msg = "omri is here";
    char buf[256];
    int len = strlen(msg);
    int byte_sent;
    int socket_dect; // creating socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_in ServerInfo;
    // creating a new socket, its a number represent a file descriptor
    // socket args : 1)ip protocol ipv4,second tcp/udp, third is number of protocol used
    socket_dect = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(socket_dect == -1){
        perror("error creating socket");
    }
    // fill the values of the server
    ServerInfo.sin_family = AF_INET; // ipv4
    ServerInfo.sin_port = htons(PORT); // port number
    //ServerInfo.sin_addr = 127.0.0.1; 
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &ServerInfo.sin_addr);//insert the ip to the sin addr

    // making the connection to the server
    //ServerInfo.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); // another way to put ip addr
    connect(socket_dect,(struct sockaddr *)&ServerInfo,sizeof(ServerInfo)); // connected to the server

    //signal(SIGALRM,sigAlarm);
    // seng data
    if(send(socket_dect,msg,len,0) < 0){
        perror("send connection");
        printf("send error");
    }
    if(recv(socket_dect,buf,len,0) < 0 ){
        printf("recv error");
    }
    printf("the data reviced from the server is :%s\n",buf);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *input(char *output) 
{
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    int count = 0;

    printf("%s", output);
    count = getline(&buffer, &size, stdin);
    buffer[count-1] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

char *msg=input("Enter the message");
```

After that use send.

EDIT: You want to implement this function I wrote above. After that you will make a while loop:

```
while(1)
{
    msg=input("Enter the message");
    send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
}
```

This will allow you to have infinite loop of entering a message and sending it to server.

Comment: can you explain what this could should do and how it can fix my problem?
just to make sure i make myself clear - when i run the client i want him to be in a endless loop, and when the user type somthing in the cli i want to send it.

Comment: well it works but the "input" is just like scanf, it blocks the program. i want to find a way to take the data from the user without using input/scanf commands. maybe I cant read it from stdin or something like that?
while the while(1) is running, the user see the cli and can write data. i want to catch it and send it to the server.

Comment: I don't exactly understand you tho, but I think you want to send the data in real time without blocking the program? I could suggest you writing in file and let the program get it from file and send it to server.

Comment: This while-loop is a black memory hole ... :-/ you defintly want to add a `free(msg);` after the `send()`.

Comment: Also `getline()` returns `ssize_t` not `int`.

Comment: You're totally right alk, but I thought it was obivous lol. Was at work at that moment so I wanted just to give some hints.

Comment: hey guys, think I found what I was looking for.
the function is select().
thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh you wanted to work with multiple connections. Then I could suggest you epoll. Read about it, it's quite simple to use and it's very powerful. Good luck.